# Cassandra on Windows, uname -o not supported

Tags: windows, cassandra

How do I start Cassandra on Windows? 
And what does my environment have to look like?

I am getting an error when starting Cassandra on Windows... uname -o not supported. 
I am using uname (GNU sh-utils) 2.0
I am not running in cygwin but just a pure powershell Window.

My Cassandra version comes **directly from git**

Here is what I tried:

```
D:\dev\3rdparty\cassandra\cassandra [trunk +1 ~0 -0 !]> .\bin\cassandra.bat -v -f
Detected powershell execution permissions.  Running with enhanced startup scripts.
Sourcing cassandra config file: D:/dev/3rdparty/cassandra/cassandra/conf/cassandra-env.ps1
Setting up Cassandra environment
Starting cassandra server
Running cassandra with: [java.exe  -javaagent:"D:\dev\3rdparty\cassandra\cassandra\lib\jamm-0.2.6.jar" -ea -Dlog4j.defa
ultInitOverride=true -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled -XX:+UseThreadPriorities -XX:ThreadPriorityPolicy=42 -Xms3072M -Xmx3
072M -Xmn768M -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Xss256k -XX:StringTableSize=1000003 -XX:+UseParNewGC -XX:+UseConcMarkSwe
epGC -XX:+CMSParallelRemarkEnabled -XX:SurvivorRatio=8 -XX:MaxTenuringThreshold=1 -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=75
 -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly -XX:+UseTLAB -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=71
99 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false  -Dlog4j.configuration=lo
g4j-server.properties -Dcassandra -Dlogback.configurationFile=logback.xml -Dcassandra.logdir="D:\dev\3rdparty\cassandra
\cassandra/logs" -Dcassandra.storagedir="D:\dev\3rdparty\cassandra\cassandra/data" -cp "D:\dev\3rdparty\cassandra\cassa
ndra\conf";"D:/dev/3rdparty/cassandra/cassandra/lib/airline-0.6.jar";"D:/dev/3rdparty/cassandra/cassandra/lib/antlr-run
time-3.5.2.jar";"D:/dev/3rdparty/cassandra/cassandra/lib/commons-cli-1.1.jar";"D:/dev/3rdparty/cassandra/cassandra/lib/
commons-codec-1.2.jar";"D:/dev/3rdparty/cassandra/cassandra/lib/commons-lang3-3.1.jar";"D:/dev/3rdparty/cassandra/cassa
ndra/lib/commons-math3-3.2.jar";"D:/dev/3rdparty/cassandra/cassandra/lib/compress-lzf-0.8.4.jar";"D:/dev/3rdparty/cassa
ndra/cassandra/lib/concurrentlinkedhashmap-lru-1.4.jar";"D:/dev/3rdparty/cassandra/cassandra/lib/disruptor-3.0.1.jar";"
D:/dev/3rdparty/cassandra/cassandra/lib/guava-16.0.jar";"D:/dev/3rdparty/cassandra/cassandra/lib/high-scale-lib-1.0.6.j
ar";"D:/dev/3rdparty/cassandra/cassandra/lib/jackson-core-asl-1.9.2.jar";"D:/dev/3rdparty/cassandra/cassandra/lib/jacks
on-mapper-asl-1.9.2.jar";"D:/dev/3rdparty/cassandra/cassandra/lib/jamm-0.2.6.jar";"D:/dev/3rdparty/cassandra/cassandra/
lib/javax.inject.jar";"D:/dev/3rdparty/cassandra/cassandra/lib/jbcrypt-0.3m.jar";"D:/dev/3rdparty/cassandra/cassandra/l
ib/jline-1.0.jar";"D:/dev/3rdparty/cassandra/cassandra/lib/jna-4.0.0.jar";"D:/dev/3rdparty/cassandra/cassandra/lib/json
-simple-1.1.jar";"D:/dev/3rdparty/cassandra/cassandra/lib/libthrift-0.9.1.jar";"D:/dev/3rdparty/cassandra/cassandra/lib
/logback-classic-1.1.2.jar";"D:/dev/3rdparty/cassandra/cassandra/lib/logback-core-1.1.2.jar";"D:/dev/3rdparty/cassandra
/cassandra/lib/lz4-1.2.0.jar";"D:/dev/3rdparty/cassandra/cassandra/lib/metrics-core-2.2.0.jar";"D:/dev/3rdparty/cassand
ra/cassandra/lib/netty-all-4.0.20.Final.jar";"D:/dev/3rdparty/cassandra/cassandra/lib/reporter-config-2.1.0.jar";"D:/de
v/3rdparty/cassandra/cassandra/lib/slf4j-api-1.7.2.jar";"D:/dev/3rdparty/cassandra/cassandra/lib/snakeyaml-1.11.jar";"D
:/dev/3rdparty/cassandra/cassandra/lib/snappy-java-1.0.5.1.jar";"D:/dev/3rdparty/cassandra/cassandra/lib/stream-2.5.2.j
ar";"D:/dev/3rdparty/cassandra/cassandra/lib/stringtemplate-4.0.2.jar";"D:/dev/3rdparty/cassandra/cassandra/lib/super-c
sv-2.1.0.jar";"D:/dev/3rdparty/cassandra/cassandra/lib/thrift-server-0.3.5.jar";"D:\dev\3rdparty\cassandra\cassandra\bu
ild\classes\main";"D:\dev\3rdparty\cassandra\cassandra\build\classes\thrift" "org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDae
mon"]
"C:/Users/las1/AppData/Local/GitHub/PortableGit_054f2e797ebafd44a30203088cd3d58663c627ef/bin/**uname.exe": invalid option -- o**
Try `"C:/Users/las1/AppData/Local/GitHub/PortableGit_054f2e797ebafd44a30203088cd3d58663c627ef/bin/uname.exe" --help' for
 more information.
Error occurred during initialization of VM
Could not reserve enough space for object heap
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
```

Answer (score 0):

May be you didn't set environment variable properly..

you have to set cassandra_home in environment variables under user variables till below point.

```
CASSANDRA_HOME : D:\dev\3rdparty\cassandra\cassandra
```

-> 2nd thing error is suggesting

-Xms3072M -Xmx3072M this are much more

Xms should be around 1 gb or half of your Xmx and Xmx should be 1/2 of RAM size..

so according to your system's ram change this two things into cassandra-env.sh file under cassandra/conf